# jQuery Dialog in ASCX will not close

Tags: jquery, .net, jquery-ui, user-controls, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm working on a dialog that loads an external page with a small 2 page form in it. Opening the dialog and using the form work fine until I get to closing the dialog. I have a button in the second page that is meant to call dialog("close"), but it never closes the dialog.

I have this all wrapped up in a .Net user control, I had hoped it would solve the issue, but nothing seems to work. The control code is below.

I have tried some of the solutions found on here. I have tried keeping the script tags for jQuery and jQuery UI in the ASCX only, as well as the parent page and master. I have also tried the buttons option of the dialog and that did not work either.

Right now I am not getting any error, just nothing happens. If I try to do a $("#dialog").dialog("close"); in the console, I get the error: "Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'"

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to get this dialog to close properly?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SchedulerPopup.ascx.cs" Inherits="sandbox.SchedulerPopup" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<style type="text/css">
.hidden { display: none; }
#header { float: left; width: 600px; }
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#dayList {
    font: normal 13px Arial;
    background-color: #EEE;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#FAFAFA),to(#DADADA));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#FAFAFA,#DADADA);
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#dayList li { 
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #BBB;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    color: #222;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-width: 15px;
    padding: 0px 9px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px #EEE;
    }
#dayList li:first-of-type { 
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 white;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 #fff; 
    }
#dayList li:last-of-type {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#dayList li.click {
    background-color: #787878;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#989898),to(dimGray));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#989898,dimGray);
    border-color: #666;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: -1px 0 -1px -1px;
    padding: 1px 9px 1px 9px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px #4C4C4C;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    clear: both;
}
.input { width: 320px; }
#lblReportName { font-style: italic; }
#dayOfWeek { margin: 0; }
#dayOfMonth { height: 26px; }
#btnSubmit, #btnClose { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 485,
        height: 280,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        title: "Email Scheduler",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load("EmailSchedulerPopup.aspx")
        }
    });
    $("#popupScheduler").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
    $("#ddlFrequency").change(function () {
        var freq = $("#ddlFrequency").val();
        switch (freq) {
            case "once":
                $("#dayOfWeek").hide("fade", {}, 150);
                $("#dayOfMonth").hide("fade", {}, 150);
                break;
            case "daily":
                $("#dayOfWeek").hide("fade", {}, 150);
                $("#dayOfMonth").hide("fade", {}, 150);
                break;
            case "weekly":
                $("#dayOfMonth").hide("fade", {}, 150, function () {
                    $("#dayOfWeek").show("fade", {}, 300);
                });
                break;
            case "monthly":
                $("#dayOfWeek").hide("fade", {}, 150, function () {
                    $("#dayOfMonth").show("fade", {}, 300);
                });
                break;
            case "quarterly":
                $("#dayOfWeek").hide("fade", {}, 150);
                $("#dayOfMonth").hide("fade", {}, 150);
                break;
        }
    })
    $("#dayList li").click(function () {
        var interval = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#dayList li").addClass("click").not(this).removeClass("click");
        $("#txtDayInterval").val(interval);
    });
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        console.log("button clicked");
        var from = $("#txtFrom").val();
        var to = $("#txtTo").val();
        var subject = $("#txtSubject").val();
        var interval = $("#ddlFrequency").val();
        var day = $("#txtDayInterval").val();
        var data = "{ \"sFrom\" : \"" + from + "\", \"sTo\" : \"" + to + "\", \"sSubject\" : \"" + subject + "\", \"sInterval\" : \"" + interval + "\", \"iDay\" : \"" + day + "\"}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "EmailSchedulerPopup.aspx/CreateEmailSchedule",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#formTable").hide();
                $("#message").show();
                $("#btnClose").click(function () {
                    console.log("close button clicked");
                    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                });
                $("#lnkCancel").click(function () {
                    console.log("close link clicked");
                    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                });
                console.log("The call to the server side succeeded.");
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                console.log("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a id="popupScheduler" href="#" >clicky</a>

<div id="dialog">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        <input id="txtDayInterval" type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" />
        <table id="formTable" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td><label>Email Report:</label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblReportName" runat="server" CssClass="input">Gain on Sale</asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>From</label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>To</label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Subject</label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Frequency</label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFrequency" runat="server" >
                        <%--<asp:ListItem Value="once">Once</asp:ListItem>--%>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="daily">Daily</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="weekly">Weekly</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="monthly">Monthly</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="quarterly">Quarterly</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="dayOfWeek" class="hidden">
                <td><label>Day of Week</label></td>
                <td>
                    <ul id="dayList">
                        <li class="0">Sun</li>
                        <li class="1">Mon</li>
                        <li class="2">Tues</li>
                        <li class="3">Wed</li>
                        <li class="4">Thurs</li>
                        <li class="5">Fri</li>
                        <li class="6">Sat</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="dayOfMonth" class="hidden">
                <td><label>Day of Month</label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDayOfMonth" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">1st</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">2nd</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">3rd</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">4th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">5th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">6th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6">7th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="7">8th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="8">9th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="9">10th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="10">11th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="11">12th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="12">13th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="13">14th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="14">15th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="15">16th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="16">17th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="17">18th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="18">19th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="19">20th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="20">21st</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="21">22nd</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="22">23rd</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="23">24th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="24">25th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="25">26th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="26">27th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="27">28th</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="31">Last Day</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"><img src="Images/buttonAddSchedule.JPG" /></asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" NavigateUrl="#"></asp:HyperLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="message" runat="server" class="hidden">
            <p>
                Your email has successfully been scheduled.
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="btnClose" runat="server"><img src="Images/buttonClose.JPG" /></asp:HyperLink>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's way to much irrelevant code here. Boil it down to the smallest reproducible example please.

Comment: how do you open the dialog?

Comment: Try replacing `<asp:HyperLink ID="btnClose" runat="server">` with `<a id="btnClose">`. The client ID of a server-side control will not necessarily match the ID property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
```

To

```
$("#dialog").dialog("destroy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of closing.

```
$(this).dialog('destroy');
```

Or maybe try to add the close button inside of the dialog.

```
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 485,
    height: 280,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    title: "Email Scheduler",
    buttons: {
      "Close": function () {
          $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).load("EmailSchedulerPopup.aspx")
    }
});
```

Comment: I just gave both of those a shot, and I am getting the same issue. Nothing happens to the dialog, and depending on how I bind to the click I either get no error, or I get the cannot call methods error.

Comment: Do you include jquery in the new pages you load? That could be the problem if you are including jquery and jqueryui in the main page and the new pages you are loading.

Comment: The scripts actually are included in the ascx itself and the master page. What is weird is that changing them so the scripts are included in one spot only, even with the destroy, doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: Try not including the scripts in the ascx and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I gave that a shot, removed the scripts from the ascx, so only the master page had them. I am getting the cannot call methods error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a variable to hold a reference to the control at the top of your script:

```
var OpenDialog = $("#dialog");
```

Then in every place you use `$("#dialog")` replace it with `OpenDialog`.

I have experienced this issue with self referencing dialogs. By making a global reference to the element you may have better luck accessing it.